# Books and music makes life even better

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement

What is correct:

> 1) Books and music make**s** life even better

or

> 2) Books and music make life even better

(saw a quote #1 and t-shirt with #2)

Comment: #1 is ungrammatical, but perhaps it's ironic commentary.

Comment: #1 could possibly be correct in the context that books and music are closely linked, as forms of intellectual/cultural stimulation — just as bacon and eggs is my favorite breakfast, and peanut butter and jelly is my favorite sandwich.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on intent and logic, both expressions could be right. If you choose to establish a connection between music and books, or, if you wish to herald that they (music and books) go in tandem then

> Music and books makes/is/has/…

will be appropriate – just as:

> Chicken and chips is good for lunch.

But, if the two matters are considered separate or separately, then a plural verb will suffice:

> Music and books make/are/have/…